# Is it possible to strip javascript JSDoc in given source code using regular expression's capturing group?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to know that is it possible to strip javascript JSDoc using capture group, mine is not working.

So I want these parts(screenshot):

[image]

screenshot's code:

```js
/**
 */

function emptyMatch() {}

/**
 * This is cool
 * Amazing
 */

/**
 * This is cool
 *
*/
function coolMatch() {}

/**
 * This should not be matched.

 */
function noMatch() {}
```

The result what I want looks like this:

```js
['This is cool\nAmazing', 'This is cool'];
```

I have written a regex:

```js
const re = /\/\*{2}\n(?:(?:[ ]*\*(?:[ ](.*))*)\n)+[ ]*\*\//g;
```

This regex in [regexr](https://regexr.com/) looks like this:

[image]

Now, when I execute this regex, it didn't show what I want.

```js
// syntax is not wrong, be carefull syntax highlighting.

const str = `/**
 */

function emptyMatch() {}

/**
 * This is cool
 * Amazing
 */

/**
 * This is cool
 *
*/
function coolMatch() {}

/**
 * This should not be matched.

 */
function noMatch() {}
`

const re = /\/\*{2}\n(?:(?:[ ]*\*(?:[ ](.*))*)\n)+[ ]*\*\//g;

re.exec(str)
```

It only shows a piece of captured string.

[image]
(I can't console.log this, sorry)

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Or, `let rx = /\/\*{2}(\r?\n(?:[\t ]*\*(?:[ \t]+.*)*\r?\n)+[ \t]*)\*\//g;
    let matches = [], m;
    while ( m=rx.exec(str)) {
      matches.push(m[1].replace(/^\s*\*\s*/gm, '').trim());
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to extract each line in the comment separately, since you don't know in advance how many lines there will be. First match every comment section, then split by newlines:

```js
const str = `/**
 */

function emptyMatch() {}

/**
 * This is cool
 * Amazing
 */

/**
 * This is cool
 *
*/
function coolMatch() {}

/**
 * This should not be matched.

 */
function noMatch() {}`;
const re = /^\/\*{2}\n((?: \*.*\n)+)+ ?\*\//gm;
let match;
while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  const lines = match[1]
    .split('\n')
    .map(line => line.slice(3)); // Remove the leading ` * ` from every line
  lines.pop(); // the last element is an empty string
  console.log(lines);
}
```

(note that the second match has an empty string in the second position because there is a line containing only `*` below `This is cool` - if that's not desirable, you can `filter(Boolean)` instead of `pop()`)